# StripeException: Missing required param: cancel_url Error in ABP IO Payment Module

Tags: stripe-payments, abp

I am receiving this error while integrating the payment module of the ABP IO. How can I set this parameter? I searched through the ABP documentation, but could not find a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should define a `RootUrl` on your [PaymentWebOptions](https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/5.0/modules/payment#paymentweboptions).

> Cancel_url: The URL the customer will be directed to if they decide to cancel payment and return to your website.